# OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.FindsBy parameters

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

What does the Priority parameter of the FindsBy attribute from OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects do? I am interested in the C# version of the library.

Is there any documentation out there regarding this?

Comment: You can download the source code at:

http://selenium.googlecode.com

This way you can see exactly what the code is doing.

The entire C# API has documentation that lives here:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/index.html (although doesn't mention the Priority property so it may be a little out of date).

It seems priority was implemented for this issue:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?can=2&q=3870&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&id=3870

Comment: Looking at the source code, seems to suggest Priority is used for ordering FindsByAttributes when you initialise a PageObject using PageFactory.InitElements.

Comment: @Arran  thanks for pointing me to the code, always the best source of information in this cases.

Answer (score 0):

Following Arran's comments the answer is:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating where this attribute should be evaluated relative to other instances
    /// of this attribute decorating the same class member.
    /// </summary>
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Priority { get; set;
```